# Allocating staff to 30 minute intervals

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to create either a spreadsheet or macro that allows me to put and employee start and finish time in and then show me by each half hour how many half hours they are in.

For example;

Employee 1 - 08:30 to 10:15

The output I would want is;

```
08:00    0
08:30    1
09:00    1
09:30    1
10:00    0.5
10:30    0
11:00    0
```

So between 8:30 and 9:00 shows as one because that employee was in during that half hour. But between 10:00 and 10:30 it shows 0.5 because the employee was only in for half of that period

Then as I add more data it tells me which half hours they are covering.

I’ve tried using the ceiling and floor values, counta, countif, countifs, v and hlookups but just can’t get the desired effect.

I’m guessing it would need to be a macro.

Comment: Will the time stamps always be on the same date? I.E. does any shift cross over midnight

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] as a sample of what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you @jdv I’m new to this but will make sure I include the above when submitting another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `C1` and `D1` contain the start and end times of a shift and column `A` contains the times, use the following formula in column `B`:

```
=IF(A2>D$1,C2,IF(AND(A2>=C$1,A3<=D$1),1,MAX(0,A3-D$1)/(1/48)))
```

Limitations: shifts cannot cross over days, days cannot start before 00:00 or end after 23:59

Comment: This is great thank you. I just need to tweak the MAX statement as it currently gives the time left in the period rather than time taken. The rest is spot on!